# Unix Make: script that creates multiple files

Tags: unix, makefile

I just started trying to use `make` for my data analyses pipelines, but I've run into a snag. Most of my scripts have one input file and one output file, which makes it very easy to create rules. Some, however, creates several output files, which creates problems with how far I've come in knowing how `make` works. For example...

```
all:    results/list.txt \
        results/stats.txt \
        results/image.png

.PHONY: all

results/list.txt results/stats.txt results/image.png: analysis.R data.txt
        $^ results/ -c blue,red -p
```

... where `analysis.R` takes a directory and outputs the three files named. While the above recepe works fine and does output the three files, the script is run three times, rather than just one. I think `make` sees that the it needs to build all three files, and then calls the scripts three times because it thinks it needs a separate call for each.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get it to run only once? Is there some clever way to create rules for scripts that have more than one output?

Comment: Use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) with `-x` and/or `make --trace` to debug Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps add some other phony target:

```
 .PHONY: all doresults
```

with a rule running the test:

```
 doresults: analysis.R data.txt
     $^ results/ -c blue,red -p
```

and

```
 all: doresults
```

or consider using some timestamp file....

Comment: The timestamp file is probably the easier workaround in that case.

Comment: Using a timestamp file worked great! Added `results/.timestamp` to `all`, and `touch results/.timestamp` to the rule with the analysis. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to remove the timestamp with `make clean` and have `clean` be also some `.PHONY` target